# how to i reverse a css animation without reversing the timing function?

Tags: css-animations

If have the following keyframe rule:

```
@keyframes bounceIn {
 0% {transform:translateX(0);}
 60% {transform:translateX(18rem);}
 100% (transform:translateX(15rem);}   
}
```

And then add it to an element like this:

```
.myDiv {
 animation: bounceIn .5s ease;
 animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

Then the timing function gets reversed too. Is there a way to avoid the timing function from going in reverse, or is there a timing function that is the reversed of ease that i can use?

Im interested in this because, otherwise i would have to write 2 @keyframe rules in order to get the reversed animation but with ease as a timing function going both ways.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`reverse` is an essential tool of preventing code duplication, however with the timing function behaving differently it is less useful than it could be.

The solution is to find such a timing function that would act as the inverse of the original timing function

```
.myDiv {  
    animation: bounceIn .5s inverse(ease) reverse;
}
```

Of course there is no such construct as `inverse(ease)` but all timing functions being cubic bezier functions, we need another cubic bezier that will behave like the original when interpreted in reverse.
The definition for the built-in timing functions can be found in the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-easing-1/#cubic-bezier-timing-functions)

e.g. `ease` is `cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)`.

Denote that as `cubic-bezier(A, B, C, D)`.

The inverse of `ease` will be a `cubic-bezier(1-C, 1-D, 1-A, 1-B)` which becomes `cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.75, 0.9)`

Use that in your code

```
.myDiv {  
    animation: bounceIn .5s cubic-bezier(.75, 0, .75, .9) reverse;
}
```

Interestingly, the inverse of the `ease-in-out` gets you the same `ease-in-out`, so if you want a timing function that behaves exactly the same when interpreted in reverse, use that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
animation-iteration-count: 2;
```

**or**

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
animation-direction: alternate;
```

**So...**

```
animation: bounceIn .5s ease infinite alternate;
```

Comment: Wouldnt this reverse the timing function too? What if a just want to use the keyframe once, but in reverse - but without reversing the timing function?

Answer (score 0):

Time Functions with normal and reverse.

ease

```
Equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)
```

ease-in

```
Equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 1, 1)
```

ease-out

```
Equivalent to cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1)
```

ease-in-out

```
Equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1)
```

Reverse ease

```
Equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.75, 0, 0.75, 0.9).
```

Reverse ease-in

```
Equivalent to cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1)
```

Reverse ease-out

```
Equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 1, 1)
```

Reverse ease-in-out

```
Equivalent to cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1)
```